# How to get the color of the button?[even tried using getCssValue] unable to fetch?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

iam just learning selenium ,i face difficulty in finding the color of the button.
Link:http://www.zillow.com/mortgage-rates/#request=ZR-MTPXYQM
Here i just need to get the color of the button "View Details" ,but i am unable to fetch it. 
code which i tried is below,pls suggest some ways to get the colour of the button.

```
WebDriver a2=new FirefoxDriver();
a2.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30l, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
a2.get("http://www.zillow.com/mortgage-rates/");
WebElement a3=a2.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@id='yui_3_15_0_1_1414204545523_500']  //button"));
System.out.println(a3.getCssValue("background-color"));
System.out.println(a2.findElement(a3.getCssValue("color"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   a3.getCssValue("background-color")
```

Is the way to go. Check if your selector matches properly

```
    WebElement a3=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.zsg-button_primary"));
    System.out.println(Color.fromString(a3.getCssValue("background-color")).asHex());
```

prints #0074e4 , looks right to me

Comment: Thanks ,it is working fine ..
but i still wonder ,why my code doesn't fetch the color?.